# Internet explorer z-index issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

On this website: http://rwl.rwlwater.com/ when I have more menus, it moves the search bar on the next line, but it's still visible over the featured slider. In firefox this doesn't happen and the search bar is not visible.

I tried changing the z-index for the slider div, for the search bar div, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set each of the elements as "position:relative"? Have you set a doctype for ie to use?

Comment: It doesn't work even in IE9, the issue is not only with ie7 and ie8 .And yes, I tried settings position: relative to all the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the divs you're trying to stack are in two different contexts (i.e. they are nested in other divs so they are not sibilings) you're not going to be able to set their z-index directly.

I think you'll have to set the z-index of the parent that is an actual sibling of the other...so since #top and #content-full are sibilings, you can need to set the z-index of #top with a higher number. This also means you'll have to position #top to something other than it's default static.

Comment: I changed the z-index for content-full  to 100 and it worked ! Thanks